# Finding a specific character in a file in Qt

Tags: qt

How can i find a specific character in a QFile which has a text in it?

for example i have ' $5000 ' written somewhere in my file.  in want to find the "$" sign so i will realize that I've reached the number.

I tried using  QString QTextStream::read(qint64 maxlen)   by putting 1 as the maxlen :

```
QFile myfile("myfile.txt");
myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);

QTextStream myfile_stream(&myfile);

  while(! myfile_stream.atEnd())
          {
              if(   myfile_stream.read(1) == '$')
               {

                  qDebug()<<"found";
                  break;
              }
          }
```

and i get "error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*  "

i also tried using the operator[] but apparently it can't be used for files.

Answer (score 1):

Read in a line at a time and search the text that you've read in

```
QTextStream stream(&myFile);
QString line;
do 
{
    line = stream.readLine();
    if(line.contains("$"))
    {
        qDebug()<<"found";
        break;
    }
} while (!line.isNull());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you've posted doesn't match the issue in your code. Possibly the error was caused by something else.

`QTextStream::read` returns `QString`. You can't compare `QString` and `const char*` directly, but `operator[]` can help:

```
QString s = stream.read(1);
if (s.count() == 1) {
  if (s[0] == '$') {
    //...
  }
}
```

However reading a file by too small pieces will be very slow. If your file is small enough, you can read it all at once:

```
QString s = stream.readAll();
int index = s.indexOf('$');
```

If your file is large, it's better to read file by small chunks (1024 bytes for example) and calculate the index of found character using `indexOf` result and count of already read chunks.

Answer (score 0):

a single char could be read with

```
QTextStream myfile_stream(&myfile);
QChar c;
while (!myfile_stream.atEnd())
  myfile_stream >> c;
  if (c == '$') {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`myfile_stream.read(1)` - this is not good practice, you should not read from file one byte at a time. Either read the entire file, or buffered/line by line if there is a risk for the file to be too big to fit in memory.

The error you get is because you compare a `QString` for equality with a character literal - needless to say that is not going to work as expected. A string is a string even if there is only one character in it. As advised - use either the `[]` operator or better off for reading - `QString::at() const` which is guaranteed to create no extra copy. You don't use it on the `QFile`, nor on the `QTextStream`, but on the `QString` that is returned from the `read()` method of the text stream targeted at the file.

Once you have the text in memory, you can either use the regular `QString` methods like `indexOf()` to search for the index of a contained character.

Answer (score 0):

> in want to find the "$" sign so i will realize that I've reached the
>   number.

It sounds to me that you're searching for the '$' symbol because you're more interested in the dollar value that follows it. In this case, I suggest reading the files line by line and running them through a `QRegExp` to extract any values you're looking for.

```
QRegExp dollarFind("\\$(\\d+)");
while(!myfile_stream.atEnd()){
    QString line = myfile_stream.readLine();
    if (dollarFind.exactMatch(line)){
        QStringList dollars = dollarFind.capturedTexts();
        qDebug() << "Dollar values found: " << dollars.join(", ");
    }
}
```